# API call for OWD (Organization-Wide Defaults) Sharing Settings objects

Tags: api, sharing, org-wide-defaults

How can I get only the objects with share permissions?
Only the objects I see in the table of Setup -> Security -> Sharing Settings. 
[Entity Definition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitydefinition.htm) gives all the objects with any filters.

[image: Sharing Settings]

Comment: are you trying to get Entity Definitions with a certain Default Internal/External Access?

Comment: Yes.
But I get a lot of 'Backend' objects that are not shown in the UI.

Comment: Any one? any help here?